# Using Google Spreadsheets with AdminDirectory API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api

Using Apps Script, this works.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myMail = 'me@mail.com';
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myMail);
  Logger.log(user.name.fullName);
}
```

Using the spreadsheet script editor I can't get this working.

```js
function onEdit(e) { 

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();

  if (column === 2) {

    var myMail = 'me@mail.com';
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myMail);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(user.name.fullName);
  }
}
```

Is there some kind of restriction when using spreadsheet triggers ?

Comment: Yup...see [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). You cannot access services that require authorization from a simple trigger (4th item on the restrictions list).

Comment: @Dimu Designs. Thanks! Installable triggers (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) is the way to go.